# Не передается второй параметр GET в CRON

Tags: get, cron

Добавил в крон задание:

curl http://mysite.com/myscript.php?key1=key1&key2=key2 > /dev/null 2>&1

**Содержимое myscript.php:**

```
$fp = fopen("log.txt", 'a');
flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
fwrite($fp, "\n");
fwrite($fp, print_r($_GET, true));
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);
Array
(
    [key1] => key1
)
```

Почему скрипт не видит второй параметр?

Comment: Пробел после первого значения перед знаком `&`?

Comment: Да вроде нет пробела...есть разве?)

Comment: Похоже что мой Сафари тормозит. Попробуйте другие параметры подставить.

Comment: Пробовал, второй параметр скрипт не видит скрипт и все...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать задание в таком виде:

```
wget -O - http://mysite.com/myscript.php?key1=key1&key2=key2
```

А также можете пробовать поменять `&` на `&amp;`